# Cordova / Phonegap Personal Safety App Send Background Heart Beat To Server

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, push-notification, background-process

I am building an IOS and Android app that requires the app to send a heartbeat to our server every 5 minutes in order to confirm that the app is still active (running in the background / screen lock stake).

The app is build using Corodva / Phonegap Platform and Jquery mobile. I have found several plugins online that deal with background processing in apps however none of them provide complete examples including .html page to be able to replicate an actual working example.

I would appreciate any guidance to online examples that provide automatic scheduled background processes when ever the app is turned on regardless of the state of the app (active / in background / screen lock).

I am aware that having regular scheduled background processes can have an additional battery drain. Would push-notifications a better, more stable, reliable solution where all the processing is done on the server side and then push the notification to the app.

I welcome advice, thoughts guidance

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot run background processes like this on iOS like on Android.  Maybe you can use location services to do this.

Comment: Hi nyantxr so am i better to have push notifications set up so all the precesses are done on server side and alerts sent ???) location services are they able to send a location every x minutes akin to live tracking reporting but used as a heart beat function as well and will this work even when screen is locked

Comment: iOS will allow your app to ask for some small amount of time to run in the background to fetch small amounts of data. Just because the app asks for background time does not mean that the request will be granted. You should read the following to understand what you can do. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html